# Can't get Cassandra remote access on vagrant

Tags: cassandra, vagrant, remote-access, datastax

I am using vagrant/puppet to configure a VM with Apache Cassandra. Local access (via `cqlsh`) works, but not remote access.

Here is my `Vagrantfile`

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty32'

  config.vm.define "dev" do |dev|
    dev.vm.hostname = "devbox"
    dev.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.200"
  end

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

end
```

I could show you my puppet file, but I think it would be easier/clearer to share the cassandra.yaml it generated.

https://gist.github.com/theonlylawislove/de34477b2cb34f106fa4

On the box...

```
vagrant@devbox:~$ cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
vagrant@devbox:~$ cqlsh 192.168.10.200
Connected to Test Cluster at 192.168.10.200:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.0 | CQL spec 3.3.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

From my host machine (Windows), I can ping the virtual.

```
Pinging 192.168.10.200 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.10.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.10.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.10.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.10.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.200:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

But when I try to access this Cassandra instance in my .NET project (on host) using the following code...

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("192.168.10.200").Build();
var session = cluster.Connect("test");
```

..I get this exception.

```
An exception of type 'Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException' occurred in Cassandra.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: None of the hosts tried for query are available (tried: 192.168.10.200:9042)
```

What gives?

**UPDATE**

I started over from scratch, creating an empty vagrant vm (no provisioning) and manually installed Cassandra. The same thing is happening. However, when I switched from a "private_network" to a "public_network" with bridged/DHCP, it worked.

I want to say that the ports aren't open with "private_network", but I have installed other services (RabbitMQ/Postgres) and they work with out an issue. So, why is Cassandra not working with the "private_network"?

Comment: Did you open the port for cassandra?  `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9042, host: 9042, auto_correct: true`

Comment: @jonnybazookatone, tried it and still doesn't work. it is my understanding that the port forwarding is just so I can access virtual machine ports on the host via "localhost:virtualport", no?

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry, didn't read your post properly ;x. Even so, you get the same error if you do the same on localhost when forwarding the port?

Comment: Does your client have network access to your rpc address on the CQL port?  telnet 192.168.10.200 9042

Comment: I have the same problem trying to access the thrift port(9160)

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. Can you post the relevant section of your Vagrantfile since switching to `public_network`?

Comment: @Nick, I have since changed back to ```private_network``` and all is well. Turns out, VirtualBox had some other network cards in a wrong state that was messing with my host only network adapter. I had to change all other VirtualBox network adapters to non-static IPs (resolve dynamically). Also, Cassandra takes a while to start. Be sure to give it enough time before you call it "not working". Try manually starting Cassandra yourself, and check the output to ensure that it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Vagrantfile` is using `private_network`, as in:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

Notice that when you use `vagrant ssh` you are shown some info prior the prompt which includes:

```
IP address for eth1: 192.168.33.10
```

Edit your `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yml` file (lines ~482/483) to be:

```
# rpc_address: localhost
rpc_interface: eth1
```

i.e. comment out the `rpc_address` and instead specify the `rpc_interface` as given by vagrant, then:

```
sudo service cassandra restart
```