# Cassandra no remote access with VirtualBox (using Vagrant) using host-only adapter

Tags: cassandra, virtualbox, remote-access, datastax

I have asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907092/cant-get-cassandra-remote-access-on-vagrant), but have since narrowed down my issue to be using the "host-only" network adapter, versus a bridge network (with DHCP).

I have created two Ubuntu virtuals, and have installed Cassandra (from DataStax) the same way.

The first box is using a host-only adapter...

```
dev.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.200"
```

And the second is bridged using DHCP...

```
dev.vm.network :public_network
```

The box using a "host-only" private network doesn't allow me remote access, even though the Cassandra configuration is the same. The box using a public network has remote access working just fine.

I am using Windows 10, and I am not sure if this was working on Windows 8.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/networking tech support.